# conditions for getting know currently post is adding or editing

Tags: wordpress, admin

I am working on wordpress and I have to add a metabox in case if post is editing. Is there any way to know that user is currently editing the post or add a new post.

thanks in advance. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check for action=edit query parameterin the url if you do not have a postID at that point  or/

and use get_post_type 
http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_post_type